# How to access observable values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, durandal

This is a model and I am trying to access its values. But value is in Symbol(_latestValue) and I am not sure how I can access that value.

```js
define(['services/SessionService'],
  function(SessionService) {
    var uiModel = function(index, data) {
      this.origData = data;
      this.sessionID = data.sessionID;
      this.rowNumber = index + 1;
      this.FullName = ko.observable('');
      this.accountId = ko.observable('');
      this.organizationId = ko.observable('');
      this.userId = ko.observable('');
      this.BuyerEmail = ko.observable('');
      this.Address = ko.observable('');
      this.loadSessionInfo();
    };

    uiModel.prototype.loadSessionInfo = function() {
      var self = this;
      var service = new SessionService();

      service.getSessionInfo(this.sessionID).then(function(result) {
        self.FullName(result.Buyer1Name);
        self.BuyerEmail(result.BuyerEmail);
        self.Address(result.Address);
        self.accountId(result.AccountID);
        self.organizationId(result.OrganizationID);
        self.userId(result.UserID);
      });
    };
    return uiModel;
  });
```

Attached is the image that shows values that I am receiving are in Symbol(_latestValue).
[image]

Comment: You need to `subscribe` to an observable to get the value emitted by it. `uiModel.BuyerEmail.subscribe((value) => { ... })`

Comment: @KanishkAnand I did, Can you please tell me what I should write in {..}?

Comment: It can be anything. You have the value of the observable. You can use it however you want to. For starters, you can do `console.log(value)` inside the function to check for the data emitted

Comment: @KanishkAnand console.log(value) prints the value I was expected but if I store it in var, I am still getting an object. Could you please tell me the best way to store that value in a variable?

Comment: Is the object same as what you expected?  You can create a class variable and update it when the observable emits a value. `uiModel.BuyerEmail.subscribe((value) => { this.storedValue = value})`

Comment: @KanishkAnand thank you for your answer but it did not work for me. Only time it works is when I console log, but if I try to store it in variable, I just get another object

Comment: Can you add the code snippet of its usage? I am pretty sure this is easily solvable